# Raspberry pi - QT webenginewidgets problem

Tags: raspbian, qt

I use raspberry pi and QT (version 5.7.1). When I use 
**QT += webenginewidgets** , I get an error
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets
however I try to install

```
-sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev
-sudo apt-get install libqt5webengine-data
-sudo apt-get install libqt5webchannel5-dev
```

but nothing change for me. how to use QT += webenginewidgets

Comment: What programming language are you trying to use to access "QT += webenginewidgets"? What is the code you're using (an applicable snippet)? What compiler?

Comment: C++, QTcreator, GCC, Raspian

Comment: So "QT += webenginewidgets" goes in your qmake project file? Do you `#include <QtWebEngine>`?

Comment: Also, install the requirements listed here: https://pastebin.com/8gNFVgFA

Comment: yes my code include QtWebEngine